# .NET Core 3 using IUrlHelper in ControllerBase

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I have a NET Core 3.1 REST API in and have configured the start up with `services.AddControllers` since I don't need views etc; it is also using endpoint routing.

However, I cannot generate the urls for newly created resources since the ControllerBase.Url property is null.

The code looks a bit like this..

```
pubic IActionResult Post(OrderRequest request)
{
    var order = service.CreateOrder(request);

    var url = Url.Link("Get", new { id = order.Id });

    return new CreatedResult(url, result);
}
```

So the questions are:

- Should I be injecting LinkGenerator instead.
- How can I change startup so that ControllerBase.Url is populated
- Is this a bug?

Comment: _"I cannot generate the urls for newly created resources since ControllerBase.Url is null."_ Is your meaning that the url created by IUrlHelper is null ? Could you show the relevant code that you have tried and  share the expected result ?

Comment: No ControllerBase.Url property is null